# Analytics server needing high application storage memory

Tags: elasticsearch, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

Our Application went live just a few months back. We have configured 2 mobile analytics server with 8gb of Ram space and 50GB of SAN space each. We have observed that Analytics server is utilizing a huge SAN space it's already 85% consumed on each server. Here are few more details how it is configured.

Number of Active Shards 24

Number of Nodes 2

Number of Data Nodes    2

MFP version : Server version: 7.1.0.00.20160801-2314

I have also noticed that document count is huge number almost 500K the memory it is taking is 28gb.

Is this the expectation or this is some sort of configuration issue. Is there any way to clean up and release some memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch (on which MobileFirst Operational Analytics is built) is very memory-intensive, and the memory usage is a function of how much data you have stored.  500K documents is not very much in the grand scheme of things, but the amount of SAN space and memory that uses depends on what is in the documents.  You don't mention what version (and iFix level) of MobileFirst Platform Foundation you're using, and it's difficult to guide you without knowing that information.  But, as a start, if you are collecting server logs in Operational Analytics, I'd recommend you stop doing that unless you truly need the server logs in Operational Analytics for some reason - in your application runtime, set the JNDI property "wl.analytics.logs.forward" to "false" (assuming you're using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1).  Then, in the Analytics Dashboard, set the TTL value for "TTL_ServerLogs" to a very small value, and check the box to apply the TTL value to existing documents (to do this, you must be running a more recent iFix level of MobileFirst Platform Foundation, as older builds didn't include this checkbox - again, assuming you're using 7.1).  This should purge the existing server logs, which should free up some memory and SAN space.  While you're in that panel, you may wish to set the other TTL values to a value appropriate for your environment, if you have not done so already.

If you're running something older than 7.1, or the build you're running doesn't have the checkbox to apply TTL values retroactively, the process to purge existing data is more complicated - in that case, please open a PMR and the support team can guide you.

If you can't purge data (e.g., if you have to keep collecting server logs, or save old data for a long time), you should add additional nodes to your Elasticsearch cluster to distribute the load over the additional nodes, so the resource utilization of each node will be less.

Comment: We are using Server version: 7.1.0.00.20160801-2314. I have updated my question. Thank you for the detailed information.